# Intuition regarding Taylor series for $\frac{e^z}{1-3z}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, taylor-expansion

The question asks me to find the Taylor series for $$f(z)=\frac{e^z}{1-3z}.$$

The radius of convergence is $|z|<1/3$ and I know the expansions for $e^z$ and $1/(1-3z)$ are \begin{align}
e^z &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots, \\
\frac{1}{1-3z} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(3z)^n=1+3z+9z^2+27z^3+\cdots.\\
\end{align}

Something tells me that since both series converge in the radius of convergence, I should be able to multiply them out and not worry about it. The answers provide  the first three terms of the final answer which are $$f(z)=1+4z+\frac{25}{2}z^2+\cdots$$ which I can get by multipying the expanded expressions out for $e^z$ and $1/(1-3z)$. Why is this intuition correct? Or why does it seem to be so?

Furthermore, how would I go about finding the coefficient $a_n$ for $z^n$ in the Taylor series? Since the series converge can I just multiply their coefficients together to get the new one?

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of $z^n$ in $(a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \ldots)(b_0 + b_1 z + b_2 z^2 + \ldots)$ is $a_0 b_n + a_1 b_{n-1} + \ldots + a_n b_0$.  You won't find a nice formula for this here (unless you like incomplete Gamma functions).

Comment: The answers have listed $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}3^{n-k}/k!$ so I think that there is a good formula here. The only problem is figuring out where it came from...

Comment: It's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: @jamesh625 $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^i}{i!} \cdot (3z)^j  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{3^{n-k}}{k!}$$